# Is it possible to pass the current class into another one as reference in php ? If yes, how

Tags: php

Here's what I did:

Let's suppose two classes one event and the other one GoogleCalendar.

```
class Event {
   private $googleCalendar;

   public function __construct() {
     $this->googleCalendar = new GoogleCalendar();
     $this->googleCalendar->set_event($this);
   }
}

class GoogleCalendar {
   private $event;

   public function set_event(&$event) {
      $this->event = $event;
   }
}
```

So, when I access the event element of the GoogleCalendar class, it says the object do not exist. Where is the problem ?

Thanks in advance and let me know if anything is not clear !

Etienne NOEL

Comment: "when I access the event element of the GoogleCalendar class". How do you do that exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object is automatically passed by reference, you don't need the `&$event` as an argument.

Here's an **[example](http://codepad.org/nl1qMfhJ)**:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    class a
    {
        public $prop = 'test';
        function __construct()
        {
            $b = new b();
            $b->preform_action($this);
        }
    }

    class b
    {
        public function preform_action($object)
        {
            if (is_object($object)) {
                var_dump($object);
            }
        }
    }

    $a = new a();

?>
```

Comment: Do you know why it says that the object doesn't exist ?